# Android secure a Pin attempt counter value

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

I'm currently implementing a custom pin screen login in an Android app where the user gets a fixed number of attempts before they are locked out (and thrown back to a full sign in screen). I'm having difficulty working out the best way to securely store the attempt counter value such that it cannot easily be attacked.

At the moment I'm currently storing the counter value in the shared preferences in an obfuscated form. The key is a meaningless String and the value is encrypted. There is an obvious weakness here where an attacker could just keep replacing the value in the shared preferences to the previous value to get an infinite number of attempts. They don't need to break the encryption or anything clever so it's a pretty simple attack.

Is there a better way I'm overlooking? I've thought about having a separate value stored somewhere else that is updated on each failure that the encryption could be based on. This makes it slightly harder but ultimately it just means an attacker has to restore two values in two places (so the attack is the same just slightly harder to figure out).

Comment: why don't you calculate the hash or something and if anyone changes any single value will result in different hash code which can be used to identify the modification and store the hash code and match it at runtime to identify the possible attack and take right action or block the login

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't understand how I can apply any kind of hashing without storing another value that can then be reproduced in the same way. I think ultimately the best I may be able to do is store independent values in two different ways.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I came up with something but in all honesty I cannot remember what on earth I done and I've long since left the company so I cannot look up the code I'm afraid.

Comment: I came up with the following solution. Allow entering PIN once if device is rooted and allow X attempts if device is not rooted. Because only on rooted device you can mess up app's data. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it's true you can only mess with an apps internal data store on a rooted device. There is no 100% flawless way to detect a rooted device, a determined hacker will always find a bypass.